# Java HttpClient get redirect status of first redirect

Tags: java, redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to make HTTP requests in Java. Whenever a url redirects me, I would like to know the status code of the original request and the final url. If I do not disable redirects, the status code is just the status code of the last successful request:

```
// google.com = tinyurl.com
HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpGet("https://google.com/cqvga");
HttpClient httpClient =
            HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); // 200
System.out.println(response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.LOCATION).length); // 0
```

However, if I disable redirect handling then I get the redirect status:

```
HttpClient httpClient =
            HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .disableRedirectHandling()
                    .build();
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); // 301
System.out.println(response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.LOCATION).length); // 1
```

Is there anyway without me writing my own RedirectHandler to know the original status code of my first request, *and* the final url I landed on?

Comment: isn't it be `302`?

Comment: For which url? google.com needs to be replaced with tinyurl.com. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post a url from tinyurl.com. But even with examples that are 302, the same problem still exists.